# Will Stencil's global JS duplicate scripts when using the same component multiples times?

Tags: angular, web-component, stenciljs

Can anyone tell me how Stencil's `globalScript`, works? If I use the same component multiple times, something like:

```html
<my-component></my-component>
<my-component></my-component>
<my-component></my-component>
```

will the globalScript `globalScript: 'src/global/app.ts'` in stencil.config.ts be applied 3 times?